# Basic Python Disassembly To Understand

Tags: python, cpython

I have a python file:

```
$ cat main.py 
def foo():
    x = 10
    y = 20
    return x+y

foo()
```

The python disassembly is as follows:

```
$ python -m dis main.py 
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object foo at 0x109a933b0, file "main.py", line 1>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (foo)

  6           9 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here are the questions I have:

1) in the disassembly, `1` refers to the line number in `main.py`, `LOAD_CONST` refers to the opcode in readable format. What is the majority of `0` following the opcodes and sometimes references of `(foo)`?

2) It seems that python loads the function name `foo`, then calls the opcode `CALL_FUNCTION`.  What  happens within the stack/heap from `LOAD_CONST` -> `STORE_NAME`. What is python keeping record of in the background (please as low level as possible, points to the CPython source is welcome)?

I see on https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html that `STORE_NAME`:

> STORE_NAME(namei)
>
> Implements `name = TOS`. namei is the index of name in
>   the attribute co_names of the code object. The compiler tries to use
>   STORE_FAST or STORE_GLOBAL if possible.

This however is not clear to me besides the fact that we are doing something like `foo = Top Of Stack`. Then `foo` actually is something that is in `co_name` as `co_name[namei]`. If we get into `LOAD_NAME` it brings something from `co_name` onto `TOS`. What is `co_name` (heap allocated `unordered_map`, `dict`)?

I feel like I am digging into a deeper and deeper hole, I think I should step back and see what the community can provide before going on.

Update: Now that I think of it, since we are doing something like `co_name[namei]` and if `namei` is and index. Is `co_name` simply a memory managed array?

Comment: The number after the opcode is the corresponding parameter, for those opcodes that take a parameter.  For LOAD_CONST, it's an index into the function's array of constants.  For LOAD/STORE_NAME, it's an index into the array of names.  For MAKE/CALL_FUNCTION, it's an encoding of the argument count (kwargs in the high byte, positional args in the low byte).

Answer (score 1):

Jason harper's comments explained your first two questions. But just to phrase it in another way, the numbers after the opcode names are their arguments, and the stuff in the parenthesis indicates what those arguments actually refer to. It turns out most opcode accepts one argument, and for your particular case, everything is indexed to be 0.

On your other question, LOAD_NAME is really LOAD_BY_NAME if that makes sense. It pushes function `foo` onto TOS, so that CALL_FUNCTION knows what to call.

Python stores names in a tuple called `co_names`, and it further maintains a `locals` dictionary, aka `f_locals` (accessible in Python via `locals()`). LOAD_NAME fetch a name at a specific index in `co_names` and then look it up in `locals`. Constants are directly stored in another tuple and are numerically indexed.

As for code references, please refer to `$PYPATH/Python/ceval.c` in your CPython distribution, or simply check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c).